# Как делать быстрее вычисление числа пи по Лейбницу

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def pi(*imp):
    if not imp:
        imp = 4
    else:
        imp = imp[0]
    rel_imp = '1'
    for n in range(imp + 1):
        rel_imp = rel_imp + '0'
    imp = int(rel_imp)
    del rel_imp
    return_pi = 0
    int_set_pi = 1
    for n in range(imp):
        return_pi += 1 / int_set_pi
        if int_set_pi > 0:
            int_set_pi = (int_set_pi + 2) * -1
        else:
            int_set_pi = (int_set_pi - 2) * -1
    return round(4 * return_pi, len(str(imp)) - 2)
```

Нужно как-то ускорить. Оно до 6-ого точного знака считает секунд 10, до 7-ого знака уже 120 секунд. Пытался добавить параллельное вычисление по кусочкам (asyncio), рационализм в памяти (tracemallok), сохранение уже подсчитанного (open). Но оно не помогает.

Comment: А вызывать эту функцию как, чтобы проверить работу, повертеть код? И вы надеюсь делали какое-то профилирование, выяснили, где у вас код тормозит, прежде чем пытаться оптимизировать код? )

Comment: И да, а что, правда по этой формуле для того, чтобы вычислить `N` знаков, нужен цикл из `10**N` итераций? Что-то я сомневаюсь.

Comment: @CrazyElf, ага. Я знаю где он тормозит. Вычисление с точностью до 9-ого знака требует одних операций сложения и деления - 2 * 10**9 XD

Comment: @CrazyElf, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8_(%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)#:~:text=frac%20%7B%5Cpi%20%7D%7B2%7D%7D%7D-,%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4%20%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%3A,-%7B%5Cdisplaystyle%20%7B%5Cfrac%20%7B1

Comment: Смена типа вычисления с Лейбница например на арктангенс приветствуется? Это уменьшит количество вычислений и соответственно ускорит.

Comment: @JackOwest, конечно приветствуется, только где формула? Я, конешно всего лишь в 10-ом классе, в душе не знаю как работает интеграл, но вчера пытался его написать XD.

Comment: @MrSvina Сейчас в дополнительном ответе покажу реализацию довольно быстрого алгоритма

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странноватый у вас код, я некоторые вещи поменял, чтобы `Numba` смогла заработать, ну и лишнее выкинул. Вот вам до 8 знака за пару секунд:

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def pi(imp):
    if not imp:
        imp = 4
    imp = 10**(imp+1)
    return_pi = 0
    int_set_pi = 1
    for n in range(imp):
        return_pi += 1 / int_set_pi
        if int_set_pi > 0:
            int_set_pi = (int_set_pi + 2) * -1
        else:
            int_set_pi = (int_set_pi - 2) * -1
    return round(4 * return_pi, len(str(imp)) - 2)

pi(8)
```

Вывод с таймингом:

```
3.14159265
Wall time: 1.79 s
```

`Numba` очень хорошо ускоряет простые математические вычисления в длинных циклах.

Comment: А что такое нумба? Мой код сделан вот по этому разложению - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8_(%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)#:~:text=frac%20%7B%5Cpi%20%7D%7B2%7D%7D%7D-,%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4%20%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%3A,-%7B%5Cdisplaystyle%20%7B%5Cfrac%20%7B1

Comment: Спс за пояснение. Рыться в этой вашей модной нумбе не буду, лучше проект сдам наконец XD.

Comment: `Numba` - это простой ускоритель работы кода. Без неё ваш код с такой тучей итераций не будет быстро работать, а с ней будет. Собственно, всё, что я сделал - это выкинул лишнее из вашего кода и добавил декоратор от нумбы. И стало в сотни раз быстрее считать.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать формулу Бэйли-Борвина-Плаффа, о которой можно почитать [здесь](https://pikabu.ru/story/chislo_pi_4545200)

Реализация:

```
import decimal

def pi_bbp(precision):
    decimal.getcontext().prec = precision + 1
    pi = decimal.Decimal(0)
    for k in range(precision):
        pi += (decimal.Decimal(1)/(16**k))*((decimal.Decimal(4)/(8*k+1))-(decimal.Decimal(2)/(8*k+4))-(decimal.Decimal(1)/(8*k+5))-(decimal.Decimal(1)/(8*k+6)))
    return pi
```

Запуск вычисления 1000 знаков после запятой:

```
print(pi_bbp(1000))
```

Время выполнения для 1000 знаков: **0.04690**,
10000 знаков: **28.88430**

Comment: О, вот это реально быстро. Хотя формула уже просто другая )

Comment: Я  не нашёл формулы по ссылке...

Comment: @MrSvinia https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%91%D1%8D%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код, по сути, вычисляет арктангенс единицы. Это можно значительно ускорить, используя тот факт что `arctg(1/2) + arctg(1/3) = arctg(1)`

Разложение в ряд для арктангенса выглядит так:

[image]

его простая реализация на `python`

```
def arctg(x, eps=0.0):
    res = 0
    k = 0

    while True:
        new = res + (-1)**k * x**(2*k+1)/(2*k+1)
        if abs(res - new) <= eps:
            return res
        res = new
        k += 1
```

вычисления `pi`:

```
print(4*(arctg(1/2) + arctg(1/3)))
```